# React Hook Forms Controller issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, web, react-hook-form

I am quiet new to React Hook Forms. I am trying integrate Material UI with react hook forms. I am avoiding the use of normal submit rather using onClick on a button to trigger submit, I am using controller but for some reason when I submit my values always reflect default values and not the actual values on the input.

```html
  <Controller
    name={name}
    control={control}
    defaultValue={defaultValue}
    render={() => (
      <QControl
        uiProp={uiProp}
        context={context}
        handleChange={handleChange}
      />
    )}
  />
```

```html
        <Button
          type="submit"
          className="form-actions"
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          startIcon={<SaveIcon />}
          onClick={onSubmission}
        >
```

```html
  const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

  const onSubmission = handleSubmit(onSubmit);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking through the Material UI docs and I can't find the Controller component, just the [FormControl](https://material-ui.com/api/form-control/) component.

I'm not familiar with Material UI, but I know about React and it doesn't seem that you have any `onChange` functions that are updating the values from your default, so the JS values would only be the default when you use the `onSubmit`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! The default Value prop on the controller then passes it as a value to the material ui component in props of the render prop.

Comment: Please provide example with solution